# OpenCL C/C++ dynamic binding library (win32 and more)

Tags: c++, c, dll, opencl, dynamic-linking

I'm giving a try at OpenCL, and in order to put this in production I'd like to be able to bind dynamically to OpenCL.DLL (when under Windows), in order to handle 'gracefully' the case where no OpenCL is installed on the host computer.

Is there any available library (or code snippet) that takes care of this dynamic binding in C or C++, much like GLEW does for OpenGL ? I'd like to avoid the hassle to do it myself.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://clcc.sourceforge.net/clew_8h.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I gave it a try, and it looks mostly fine. I got bitten by a silent error though : as my project was built with Unicode character set, the `const char*` for the module name given to `clewInit` was silently cast to `LPCWSTR` when the `LoadLibraryW` function was called. The LoadLibrary call then failed without what seemed a good reason. Took some time to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with Win32, the easiest solution is delay loading. If you delay-load OpenCL, and the compiler-added stub fails to find it, it will call `__pfnDliFailureHook2(dliFailLoadLib)`. You can handle the error there; if you don't provide a handler you'll get the default behavior (program aborts). In either case the program will not have a static dependency on OpenCL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Dynamic binding is more flexible and allows to bind only available entry points (in case of support of multiple versions adding/removing functions, see OpenGL) ; would delay-loading OpenCL allow to handle this case ?

Comment: Yes, your `__pfnDliFailureHook2` can also handle cases where individual functions are unavailable, that's what argument  `dliFailGetProc` is for.

Answer (score 0):

QtOpenCL http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/04/07/using-opencl-with-qt/