# Can a C/C++ application utilise OpenCL?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

This might sound a little bit silly, but I haven't found a definitive answer. I've got an application that would largely benefit from the scalability of OpenCL. But how would I go about with the existing code I have, to implement OpenCL? Would I have to use a wrapper? Do I have to port the code over to OpenCL?

Comment: You would write your computational code (the kernels) in OpenCL, but the rest could simply remain C/C++.

Comment: So wouldn't that require having the core part being OpenCL, and then everything else attached onto it? So I'd need to rewrite the whole program around the OpenCL core. Wouldn't that be a pain for extremely large programs with thousands of files? Or am I getting the wrong idea here?

Comment: I can't comment on the exact undertaking for you, since I can't see your current sources. But yes, those parts you intend to parallelize with OpenCL would have to be written in OpenCL. So most likely your core would have to be rewritten while your calling code could remain relatively similar. I don't know if your application would allow for a step-by-step conversion, but if it does you could more gradually make the switch.

Comment: You dynamically load the OpenCL library which acts as "glue" between your application and an IHV implementation. Then you get function pointers of the API functions that you want to use, and then... you use them. The end user will have to install OpenCL, but this usually happens silently with any recent graphics driver anyway. All in all, it's easy and straightforward with a few system-specific calls. There's ready to use code for that on the internet too (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5030972/572743)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper is not sufficient. You will have to rewrite your code in OpenCL C and most likely redesign your algorithms for parallel processing (running on multiple cores/threads). There is no free lunch.

Answer (score 0):

What @vocaro said.

I'd also drop in that there are attempts like [OpenHMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenHMPP) to craft a different approach to GPGPU programming, kind of what OpenMP did to multithreading. But I've yet to see a decent implementation of that.